# The Windows 7 volume slider (sndvol.exe) accesses files on my hard drive whenever I change the system volume

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, media-player, media-player-classic

I'm running Windows 7 x64. Whenever I change the volume using the default taskbar volume slider (sndvol.exe), the program accesses files on my storage hard drive.

This is extremely annoying because it spins up my hard drives when they are off/idle which means they use more power and generate noise.

The file(s) in question seem to be media files (TV episodes) which I watched several weeks ago using Media Player Classic Home Cinema. That program is no longer running, and indeed the computer has been restarted several times since then. I've also watched many other media files since that time, but this one seems to have become "stuck" to sndvol.exe, somehow.

Here's a screenshot of the phenomenon taken from ProcessExplorer:

[image: wat]

I've searched the registry for the filename with no results.

What is happening here?